# hash function to speed up union of subsets algorithm analysis

Tags: hash, time-complexity, union

Is it possible to use hash to speed up the union process of a function that takes O(n) time? I'm trying to see if its doable, or practical even. how would I do that?

Comment: Skiena, page 386: "union-find data structure", sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks, its a pretty good book